# Gnome Bluetooth not detecting devices -- Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, bluetooth

I have GNOME installed on my Arch Linux which is dual booted with a Windows 11 OS.

**Problem:**
Gnome bluetooth turns on/off but does not detect devices.
Screenshots:
When its OFF:
[image: bluetooth GUI showing it is off]

When its ON:
[image: bluetooth GUI showing it is off]

Its not detecting any nearby devices (nothing is rotating beside the "Devices" label).
BUT it (the PC) is being detected by my Samsung Phone's bluetooth but is unable to connect to it (not unusual).

I tried some other websites on the internet.
Accordingly,
When I ran `sudo rfkill list`,
Output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Also, `sudo systemctl status bluetooth`, yielded

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-05-18 23:05:56 IST; 21min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 422 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4578)
     Memory: 2.5M
        CPU: 80ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─ 422 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 18 23:05:56 Someone systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 18 23:05:57 Someone bluetoothd[422]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
May 18 23:06:51 Someone bluetoothd[422]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May 18 23:06:51 Someone bluetoothd[422]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
May 18 23:06:51 Someone bluetoothd[422]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
May 18 23:06:51 Someone bluetoothd[422]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
May 18 23:06:51 Someone bluetoothd[422]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
May 18 23:06:51 Someone bluetoothd[422]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
May 18 23:06:51 Someone bluetoothd[422]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
May 18 23:06:51 Someone bluetoothd[422]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
```

from:  https://linuxhint.com/bluetooth_arch_linux/

So, it does seem that bluetooth is working properly

##### What I tried:

Attempt 1:

1. `sudo systemctl stop bluetooth`
2. `sudo systemctl start bluetooth`
3. `reboot` >> not working

Attempt 2:

1. `sudo systemctl disable bluetooth`
2. `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth`
3. `reboot` >> no luck

Attempt 3:

1. `sudo pacman -S blueman`
2. **WORKS** well kinda...

With blueman, I have to press the search button to search for other devices and when it finds something, gnome-settings also gets updated (magically) with that but does not do any further detection...

Doesn't that solve my problem?
Ans: **Of course NOT!**

#### How Should I get gnome-settings to detect other bluetooth devices in real time?

(I had a previous Arch install with GNOME like a month ago and it did not have this problem.)

Comment: Hey did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. At least with blueman works, thanks! It must be a gnome bug

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and type

```
sudo pacman -S bluez bluez-utils blueman
```

and then turn off bluetooth and then turn on

If this dosen't works then after that trying that do this

Go to settings
-> Applications
-> Bluetooth Manager
-> Scan Devices